# How to do a method run before each service call?(Angular 7)

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I'm trying get a "payload" from localstorage before than execute services method.
Actualy i'm trying to do it on constructor method, but sometimes the variable "this.payload" isn't setted when a call a method.

This is my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as Globals from '../../globals';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RechargesService {

    public payload;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        public localStorage: LocalStorage
    ) {
        this.localStorage.getItem("payload").subscribe((payload) => {
            this.payload = payload;
        })
    }


    list(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(Globals.url_api + "recharges/list", {
            // Sometimes this.payload isn't setted, i don't know why
            "payload": this.payload
        });
    }
}
```

What's the correct way to do it? I know that in controller, i shouldn't write anything on constructor method, but in service it's correct?

Comment: I would send that payload as a parameter for the `list():` function like `list(payload)`

Comment: This works... But i would like don't write parameter everytime when i call a method... It will more simple if i can get payload from localstorage.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get payload before every `list()` call, you can do it like following:

First create a method returns an observable that gets value from local storage, then use `switchMap` to return an inner observable (which is HTTP get request)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as Globals from '../../globals';
import { Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import { tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class RechargesService {

public payload;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        public localStorage: LocalStorage
    ) {

    }

     getPayload = () => {

        return this.localStorage.getItem("payload").pipe(tap(payload => this.payload = payload)); // <--- the tap() may be redundant here. you can simply get payload in list() method

     }


    list(): Observable<any> {

        return this.getPayload().pipe(
            switchMap(payload => {
               return this.http.post(Globals.url_api + "recharges/list", {"payload": this.payload})  // <--- You can use payload instead of this.payload since localStorage already returns payload
            })
        );
    }

}
```

---

switchMap: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

do/tap: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it don't works... "A representation of any set of values over any amount of time. This is the most basic building block of RxJS." A Observable RxJS must to be the most basic structure on function...

Comment: If a function is "any" type, it should return a value... Something like this... I already did erase this code... Sorry.

Comment: I forgot to add `return` to `list()` method. Edited the question already

Comment: Now it works perfectly. Thanks :D But, could i do it using a constructor? Because i dont would like write "return this.getPayload().pipe(
            switchMap(payload => {..." on every method...

Comment: Since you use `providedIn: 'root'`, it is a singleton service which means `constructor` will be called only once on application start up. `@ngx-pwa/local-storage` performs async operation (the library is made for this), so you need to make sure the async operations is completed before going on any further.

Comment: Exactly. There is a way to force it to be a sync function, or something like this? I read local-storage documentation, but not found nothing about it.

Comment: You can search for something like "call a service method on application startup"

Answer (score 1):

create a getPayload function tp get local-storage data and use switchMap in list function to pass getPayaload data to api.

```
getPayload(){
    return this.localStorage.getItem("payload");
}

list(payload): Observable<any> {
    return getPayload().pipe(
        switchMap(
            (payload) => {
                return this.http.post(Globals.url_api + "recharges/list", {
                    payload
                })
            },
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: This works... Thanks... But, there is a way that don't need write "return getPayload().pipe(
        switchMap(..." on every function? Because this i was trying use on constructor method...

Comment: @Leandro How is this different than my answer?

Comment: @LeandroCastro if data is not updating that use once.

Answer (score 0):

Use forkJoin Operator

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

```
forkJoin(
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request One', 2000),
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request Two', 1000),
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request Three', 3000)
    )
    .subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
      this.propOne = res1;
      this.propTwo = res2;
      this.propThree = res3;
    });
```

Comment: It's not i want... I would like call "constructor" before every method... but sometimes the method is running before than constructor...